# Make Camera follow object only on Y axis?

Tags: c#, unity

Can someone give me a script that makes the camera follow a specific gameObject only on Y axis without changing the camera's X axis position, in C#?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about writing your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;

    void Update () {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, target.position.y, -10);
    }
}
```

Attach it to the camera and set `target` to desired gameObject.

Comment: Here's the thing, I want the camera to only follow the base, "the bottom" of my game object. With this code, if the object has an "Idle" animation that goes up and down like if it was breathing, the camera also goes up and down. I want the camera to only follow the base, "the bottom" of my game object.

Comment: So you need somehow to define a base of your object and set it to another object which camera will follow.

Comment: How? Can you write code?

Comment: No, I can not. The code depends on your project context which I do not know.

Comment: Nothing special. The gameObject is a cube.

Comment: I want the camera to follow the base of the cube.

Comment: I still did not find a way...

Comment: ? After 1 week, I still did not find an answer.